# what is equivalent class for AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests in Spring 4.2.5.relese

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven-3, spring-test

I was using Spring 2.5, but now using Spring 4.2.5 so due to this error occurred so I need to know that which class is use instead of this `AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests`.

[image]

Comment: @user7294900 I don't think your answer helped, because it i snot clear how you can pass the application-context.xml? Autowiring is vague.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace with `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests` see [deprecated notes](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-test/3.2.0.RELEASE/deprecated-list.html):

> as of Spring 3.0, in favor of using the listener-based test context
>   framework (AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests)

Comment: can u tell me one more thing how to replace this method ?            
            protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
  setAutowireMode(AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME);
       return new String[] {
          "applicationContext.xml"

Comment: you don't need the function. use autowire byName, see http://www.journaldev.com/2623/spring-autowired-annotation